Why doesn't my Git remote repository size reflect the larger file sizes after pushing changes?
I noticed a size discrepancy between my local and remote Git repositories. Here's the scenario:
I cloned a repository containing three files:
File1: 1 MB
File2: 1 MB
File3: 1 MB
The total size of my local repository (including .git and hidden files) is 5 MB. However, the size of the remote repository is only 2 MiB.
I made a change to File1, increasing its size to 4 MB. After pushing the changes:
The local repository size increased accordingly.
The remote repository size only increased slightly to 2.5 MiB.
Why is there such a significant difference between the local and remote repository sizes? Shouldn't the remote repository size increase proportionally with the size of the updated file?
What I Tried:
I modified File1 in my local repository, increasing its size from 1 MB to 4 MB. After committing and pushing the changes to the remote repository, I expected the remote repository size to increase proportionally to reflect the new file size.
What Actually Happened:
The remote repository size only increased slightly (from 2 MiB to 2.5 MiB), even though the local repository size increased significantly due to the updated file.
I’m trying to understand why this size discrepancy exists and how Git manages repository size differences between local and remote repositories.

What are the contents of your file 1 file 2 and file 3. Is it a text file? or a binary file?

The discrepancy in your remote repo and local repo can be explained by:
The remote repo only holds the .git folder
What is the .git folder?
Your .git folder compresses and stores a full snapshot of each commit. What this means is that it stores your project files along with meta-data and many other things required for the underlying mechanism of git to function.
Why did your local repo increase significantly after changing file 3 to 4MB
Your local repo will be holding your uncompressed project files and your .git folder. Which means that the size will be more than your remote repo because again, the remote repo only holds the .git folder which is compressed (and optimized for text files).
Note: If you are working on a big project, where there are many contributors to your remote-repo. Then most certainly the remote-repo will eventually become bigger in size than your local repo. As remote will hold all branches, history and commits made by every developer. While the developers will only hold their own branches.
